# COM Interop (vb6 --> .NET) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Automation Error

Tags: .net, vb6, com-interop, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

I am working on a legacy VB6 application that calls into a .net assembly using COM Interop.   I am getting a "-2146232576 Automation Error".  I am having problems troubleshooting the error.

The installer installs the .NET assembly into the GAC.  I have checked the registry to ensure that the correct interfaces are there for the COM Interop (they are).  I have also dropped the assembly and type libraries in place and used regasm with the /TLB and /codebase switches.  Same problem.

To simplify the process, I created a new .NET assembly with COM interface by following this post here:  http://www.geeksengine.com/article/create-dll.html

I then created a VB6 forms app (project1.exe) with one button that references the .NET assembly that looks like this:

```
Private Sub Command2_Click()
    Dim lngResult As Long

    Dim objCalc As SimpleCalc.Calc
    Set objCalc = New SimpleCalc.Calc

    objCalc.SetNumberOne (3)
    objCalc.SetNumberTwo (6)

    lngResult = objCalc.Add()

    MsgBox lngResult

End Sub
```

I copied the project1.exe, simplcalc.dll, and simplecalc.tlb onto the Windows Server 2012 R2 machine, used regasm with the /tlb and /codebase options and ran the app.

Still didn't work and got the exact same automation error as the old legacy system.  I then tried every compatibility setting (windows compatibility when you got to the properties of the EXE) under the sun with no success.

**HOWEVER**, if I take the same sample app and install it on a Windows 7 (32 bit or 64 bit), XP (32 bit), 2008 R2 (64 bit), or Windows 10 (64 bit) machine and follow the same procedures...everything works flawlessly.  No need for any compatibility settings or anything.  Just copy, register with regasm, and done.

I have looked high and low trying to find something about windows server 2012 R2 and COM Interop problems but can't find anything.

Any suggestions?

Comment: -2146232576 == 0x80131700 == CLR_E_SHIM_RUNTIMELOAD == "Failed to load the runtime."  This machine does not appear to have the correct .NET version installed.  Pretty hard to get this wrong, don't just copy Regasm.exe from another machine.

Comment: @HansPassant thank you for the response.  However, I have checked and the server has the correct framework installed (main app uses 2.0, simplified app uses 3.5 and both are installed on the machine).  I use the regasm in the c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.(numbers) folder.  I didn't copy over the regasm from another machine. It shouldn't matter that I use the v4 version to register a v2.x or v3.5 version should it?

Comment: It matters a lot.  Your COM server will now ask for the v4 version of the CLR.  Cannot work, the v2 version was already loaded.  "Failed to load the runtime" is the outcome.

Comment: @HansPassant Ok.  You nailed it the first time.  Registering with the v4.x regasm doesn't matter....however....the 3.5 framework was NOT actually installed.  I assumed it was since the c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v3.5 folder existed.  I didn't verify that it was actually installed.   Checking the registry, I only saw 4.5.  Installing 3.5 worked.  Registering with 4.x worked for the 3.5 and 2.0 components.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: Hmya, that's the mystery scenario.  Where did Regasm.exe come from if the framework was not installed?

Comment: The v4.x framework was installed.  Just not the 3.5 and below framework.  So regasm was run from the v4 folder.